# Set HTML attribute as JSON object using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, attr

I am trying to set the attribute of an HTML canvas element, but the attribute has a value, which should be an array. How should it be done? Please help.

JavaScript:

```
var labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
var series = ['Series A', 'Series B'];
var data = [
  [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
  [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
];
var datasetOverride = [{yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'}, {yAxisID: 'y-axis-2'}];
var options = {
  scales: {
    yAxes: [{
        id: 'y-axis-1',
        type: 'linear',
        display: true,
        position: 'left'
      },
      {
        id: 'y-axis-2',
        type: 'linear',
        display: true,
        position: 'right'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Trying to set attribute:

```
$('#line').attr("chart-data", data);
$('#line').attr("chart-labels", labels);
$('#line').attr("chart-series", series);
$('#line').attr("chart-options", datasetOverride );
$('#line').attr("chart-dataset-override", options);
```

HTML:

```
<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line"></canvas>
```

Comment: which attribute are you talking about ?

Comment: Set and get using `data()` instead. Attribute values only allow for strings but you can store any type using `data()`

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira I want to bind this html element through jquery

After binding it should be

`<canvas id="line" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="data"
chart-labels="labels" chart-series="series" chart-options="options"
chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride" chart-click="onClick">`

Comment: @charlietfl can you give an example  please sir

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in many ways. One of them is convert them to a string with join. Like this:

```js
var data = [
            [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
            [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        ];
var joined = data.join(',');
console.log(joined);
$('#line').attr("chart-data", joined);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="line">line</div>
```

Please inspect the div element. I used a div, so you could inspect it, but it's the same with canvas.